# When I put an array of objects to firefox (using typescript) and I get the data am I not able to get it as an array of objects?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, http, get

Saving and retrieving data from a Firebase database doesn't give me the same type of data. Below I will explain what I am doing and what I am running into:

**Saving data**

I am saving an array of `Recipe` to a Firebase database, using the following code:

```
save() {
  this.http.put(
    this.recipeURL,
    this.recipesService.getRecipes()
  ).subscribe(
    (response) => {
      console.log(response);
    }
  );
}
```

The code to retrieve the `Array` of `Recipe` objects using the `RecipeService` is very straightforward:

```
getRecipes() {
  return this.recipes.slice();
}
```

The `Recipe` model is defined as follows (nothing fancy):

```
export class Recipe {
  public id: number;
  public name: string;
  public description: string;
  public imagePath: string;
  public ingredients: Ingredient[];

  constructor(id: number, name: string, desc: string, imagePath: string, ingredients: Ingredient[]) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.description = desc;
    this.imagePath = imagePath;
    this.ingredients = ingredients;
  }
}
```

**Retrieving data**

Afterwards, I retrieve the data using the following code:

```
read() {
  this.http.get<Recipe[]>(
    this.recipeURL
  ).subscribe((recipes) => {
    console.log(recipes);
    console.log(this.recipesService.getRecipes());
  })
}
```

**The result/problem**

In the code, I am logging the response of the get method as well as the original list of `Recipe` objects that I want to replace. It seems that I am retrieving an `Array` of `Json` objects, not `Recipe` objects. Below you find a screenshot of the difference between the two, when you look at the console output.

[image]

As you see, one is an `Array` of `{...}`, the other an `Array` of `Recipe`.

Hope someone can help explaining/solving this. The problem is that, after I assign the data I got from my Firebase database, and I update my application (using a `Subject`), that my page is not showing the new data, but keeps showing the old data.

Comment: Could you share `getRecipes` function in `recipesService`?

Comment: @ahmeticat: added the code. Nothing special. In the `RecipeService`, the actual data is saved as `Recipe[]`

Comment: Could you be using `changeDetection`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be at a completely different level. The `RecipeService` was provided at the wrong component.